# Is there a way to plot OXYplot graph in custom area in WPF window?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2019, oxyplot

I want to put several graphs in one WPF window using OXYplot library, so there will be some WPF components (like buttons) and some rectangles with graphs. It there a way to do it? In all examples the OXYplot graph occupies the whole WPF window.

I tried to put it inside a rectangle like this, but got an error "The type 'Rectangle' does not support direct content"

```xml
<Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="932,547,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100">
   <oxy:PlotView Model="{Binding Model}"/>
</Rectangle>
```

Comment: See [Panels Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/panels-overview).

Answer (score 1):

Put it in a [Panel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/panels-overview) or decorate it with a a `Border`:

```
<Border Background="Yellow" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Padding="10">
    <oxy:PlotView Model="{Binding Model}"/>
</Border>
```

A `PlotView` is just a custom `Control` that you can use in your layout as you would use any other control in WPF.

Answer (score 0):

To keep it simple, you could use Grid as well, to arrange multiple PlotView and buttons in desired layout.

```
<Grid Margin="10">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <oxy:PlotView Height="500" Width="500" Model="{Binding GraphModel1}"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Click"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <oxy:PlotView Height="500" Width="500" Model="{Binding GraphModel2}"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Click"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <oxy:PlotView Height="500" Width="500" Model="{Binding GraphModel3}"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Click"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <oxy:PlotView Height="500" Width="500" Model="{Binding GraphModel4}"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Click"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```